# Can cold water decrease fat in the gut area?

Tags: stomach

Someone suggested that I drink lots of cold water in order to decrease fat.  Is this true?

Comment: Who suggested? Have you found anything to confirm that online?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's pure nonsense. Fat is caused by eating more calories than you burn. Period. The only effect drinking water might have (cold or otherwise) is to fill your stomach and therefore cause you to eat less.

Answer (score 1):

The basis for this is that drinking ice cold water will lower your body temperature a bit causing your body to react and raise it to compensate, this in turn expends a bit of energy.
While the concept may be true, the energy expenditure is so minute, it really won't make the slightest bit of a difference in you achieving weight loss.
If you want to lose weight, eat in a caloric deficit